# Testing scalability and performance for Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight

We have Silvelright application we need to test its scalability, what would be the best tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Silverlight is client-only, you really will want to test your web server and web services.

You will need to make sure:

- You can serve the .Xap files as static files to your expected visitors
- Any web service calls are properly load tested, along with the database

Any existing test tools can be used for this, no need to focus on the Silverlight part of the equation.